# Word 2021 Visual Basic database connection 64 bit not working

Tags: vba, ms-word, 64-bit

[image]This code use to work with 2013 Word 32 bit and now its not working with 2021 Word 64 bit.

```
Public Benzdb As Database
Public sconnection As String
Sub ConnecttoDatabase()
'Production System ODBC
 sconnection = OdbcConnection("dbBenz", "Benz", "username", "password")
 Set Benzdb = Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("Benz", False, False, sconnection)
End Sub

Sub CloseDatabase()
    Acedb.Close
End Sub

Public Function OdbcConnection(ByVal AceDatabaseName As String, ByVal AceDataSourceName As String, Aceuserid As String, AcePassWord As String) As String
 ODBCConnectString = "ODBC" _
 & ";DATABASE=" & BenzDatabaseName _
 & ";UID=" & Benzuserid _
 & ";PWD=" & BenzPassWord _
 & ";DSN=" & BenzDataSourceName
End Function
```

Comment: What line is the error triggered? And what is error message?

Comment: Run-time error '214722164(80040154)
Class not registered

Comment: That was question #2

Comment: Are you using 32 bit or 64 bit Access? Show a picture of your checked references in VB Editor (`Tools | References`)

Comment: Set Benzdb = Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("Benz", False, False, sconnection)

Comment: Word 2021 64 bit and SQL 2008 Server for db

Comment: Probably a reference issue - don't see your current list. `Workspaces(0)` is part of DAO - you likely need to update to current library `Microsoft Office ## Access database engine Object Library`

Comment: I added the reference image.

Comment: Perfect - Try unchecking the DAO library and then scrolling down to check `Microsoft Office ## Access database engine Object Library` - then run `Debug | Compile` to see if it allows `Workspaces` statement

Comment: Runtime error 3024 could not find file 'Benz'

Comment: Sure thing. If I put it in an answer can you mark it as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an older 32 bit reference to DAO

Try unchecking the DAO library and then scrolling down to check `Microsoft Office ## Access database engine Object Library` - then run `Debug | Compile` to see if it allows Workspaces